# Worklight with Angular js

Tags: angularjs, ibm-mobilefirst

We are working on an angular js based worklight app. So angular js has "directives" which return a piece of HTML code from html file and injects into main.html

What we observed here is, whenever there is a whitespaces/comments etc. outside an HTML tag elements, it throws an error as "https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/tplrt"
This is a known issue and documented in the angular docs.

But the strange part is, we started development in WL 6.1 and never faced this issue. As soon as we migrated to WL 6.2, this error popped up. One of the things which came to my mind is the default jquery lib(conflict), which is bundled with worklight. But I tried replacing with older jquery versions(till 1.9.1) and it didn't work. Any thoughts/suggestions on why this might be happening in 6.2??

PS: This issue is seen only in the browser and not in the emulator/device.

index.html

```
<body style="display: none;">
<!--application UI goes here-->
<shell></shell>
</body>
<script src="js/lib/angular.js"></script>
<script src="js/shell.js"></script>
```

main.js

```
// Common initialization code goes here
angular.bootstrap(document, ['shell']);
```

shell.html

```
<div id="topZone" app-view-segment="0"></div>[Insert \n here]
```

shell.js

```
angular.module('shell',[]);

angular.module('shell').directive('shell', [

function() {
    console.log('shell Directive');
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: 'views/shell.html'
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Do you have something more substantial to show? Provide a reproduction project or steps to reproduce.

Comment: Hi Idan, edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know why it did work in 6.1, it shouldn't have :)
You should use the latest version of 6.2, since there were some bugs in the preview.
[In the angularjs site](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/tplrt) it is clearly state that you need to have everything wrapped in a single HTML element:

> When a directive is declared with template (or templateUrl) and
> replace mode on, the template must have exactly one root element. That
> is, the text of the template property or the content referenced by the
> templateUrl must be contained within a single html element. For
> example, `<p>blah <em>blah</em> blah</p>` instead of simply blah
> `<em>blah</em>` blah. Otherwise, the replacement operation would
> result in a single element (the directive) being replaced with
> multiple elements or nodes, which is unsupported and not commonly
> needed in practice.

Comment: We had migrated to latest version of WL. Still the issue persists. Referring to shell.html here, if I remove [\n or whitespaces] after the div tag, it works.

Comment: the \n or whitespace is a new text node in the DOM so what is written above is still valid.